# Right align of element doesn't work properly

Tags: css

I have two "div" elements, one that should be on the left, one on the right, and one that should be under the other.

But instead, the elements “touch” each other, and I don’t need this at all.
CSS:

```
.theirmsg {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #8a8;
}
.mymsg {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #88a;
  width: 50%;
  float: right; 
  text-align: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mymsg">hello world1</div><br><div class="theirmsg">hello world2</div>
```

I tried replace  `float: right;` by `position: absolute; right: 0px`, but that didn't work neither.

Comment: You say you have two divs then describe three. Please explain.

Comment: one of THESE elements should be under the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modified code.

CSS:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mymsg {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #88a;
  align-self: flex-end;
  text-align: left;
}

.theirmsg {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #8a8;
  text-align: left;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mymsg">hello world1</div>
  <div class="theirmsg">hello world2</div>
</div>
```